# Can I sneak attack with Green-Flame Blade or Booming Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, rogue, cantrips, sneak-attack

Most spells can't be combined with sneak attack because 5e sneak attack specifies a finesse or ranged weapon attack.

However, *booming blade* and *green-flame blade* require you to "*…make a melee attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range…*"

If you're using a finesse weapon and otherwise would qualify to deal sneak attack damage on a normal melee attack, would you be able to apply sneak attack damage with these spells?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**So as long as you qualify for Sneak Attack, it applies. In your example, the melee attack would trigger Sneak Attack.**

You can even get sneak attack on an opportunity attack later in the round because it's only limited to once per *turn*. Sneak attack is not an attack action, it's a triggered event based on its prerequisites.

The official [Sage Advice Compendium confirms](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) this:

> **Can you use green-flame blade and booming blade with Extra Attack, opportunity attacks, Sneak Attack, and other weapon attack options?**
>
> Introduced in the Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide, the green-flame
>   blade and booming blade spells pose a number of questions, because
>   they each do something unusual: require you to make a melee attack
>   with a weapon as part of the spell’s casting. **First, each of these
>   spells involves a normal melee weapon attack, not a spell attack**, so
>   you use whatever ability modifier you normally use with the weapon. (A
>   spell tells you if it includes a spell attack, and neither of these
>   spells do.) For example, if you use a longsword with green-flame
>   blade, you use your Strength modifier for the weapon’s attack and
>   damage rolls.
>
> Second, neither green-flame blade nor booming blade works with Extra
>   Attack or any other feature that requires the Attack action. Like
>   other spells, these cantrips require the Cast a Spell action, not the
>   Attack action, and they can’t be used to make an opportunity attack,
>   unless a special feature allows you to do so.
>
> Third, **these weapon attacks work with Sneak Attack if they fulfill the
>   normal requirements for that feature**. For example, if you have the
>   Sneak Attack feature and cast greenflame blade with a finesse weapon,
>   you can deal Sneak Attack damage to the target of the weapon attack if
>   you have advantage on the attack roll and hit.

Comment: +1, but I think it'd be even better to have the word *reaction* in there somewhere. Like "...later in the round because--as a reaction--it's only limited..." or "...it's a triggered reaction based on...."