# Do ranged spells count as attacks for purposes of a Rogue's Sneak Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rogue, sneak-attack

Our DM was saying that an Arcane Trickster Rogue casting a Firebolt does not get the sneak attack damage on a hit. Is that right?

Comment: That question is from the playtest, so it's not really a duplicate.

Comment: @Miniman so I closed this before seeing your comment. If that question is from the playtest it sold be retagged. And I'm not 100% sure it matters if it is. Certainly the top and accepted answer is not from the playtest so I think it should be good regardless.

Comment: Yeah, there are a number of improperly tagged questions from the playtest that never got fixed so there are a mix of playtest answers and official 5e answers. I'm unsure how we deal with those...

Comment: @V2Blast might be worth a meta honestly.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: Someone else can ask it, or I can do it some other time. Right now I have to sleep so I can be awake for a work call in 5 and a half hours...

Answer (score 7):

### Spells cannot be used for sneak attacks....

... unless the spell involves making a weapon attack as part of its action, such as [Greenflame-Blade and Booming Blade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83147/can-i-sneak-attack-with-green-flame-blade-or-booming-blade), in which case, you can apply sneak damage.

> **Sneak Attack** (PHB Pg. 96)
>
> Once per turn, you can deal extra 1d6 damage to one
> creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack
> roll. ***The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.***

Comment: If the spell includes a weapon attack, it can be used for sneak attacks (assuming the weapon used is light or finesse).

Comment: Yeah, I over-looked that. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for sneak attack state:

> The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.

A spell is not a finesse weapon, nor is it a ranged weapon, so no sneak attack damage can be applied from casting it.

Comment: Some spells specify that they are a finesse weapons, such as Shadow Blade (https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/shadow-blade). My interpretation is that these spells could qualify for sneak attack.